# virsh list print guest name

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am running latest `Ubuntu 20.04` with KVM and when i run `virsh list` command it print UUID of guest vm instead of their real name hostname. (you can see in following output vm name is random UUID `instance-00000005`)

```
root@os-lab-comp-sriov-0:~# virsh list
 Id   Name                State
-----------------------------------
 1    instance-00000005   running
```

My versions

```
# virsh --version
6.0.0
# qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10)
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

I have noticed on this blog, its showing real name of guest vm - https://ravada.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/config_console.html

Answer (score 0):

`virsh list` lists the given names of the VMs, not the hostnames. You can give a VM a name with --name option at virt-install command. I guess your host was given a random name, because no name was specified when creating it.

To display the hostname of a VM (domain as QEMU and KVM say) you can use following command at your case:

```
virsh domhostname instance-00000005
```

Or more spefically:

```
virsh domhostname DOMAINNAME
```

Comment: It is openstack creating those VM, may be there must be reason to use UUID, you command giving me error `error: failed to get hostname` and `error: argument unsupported: QEMU guest agent is not configured`

Comment: That error happens when the VM is powered off. I mean the command only runs when the VM is running.